# Constrained optimization-Book recommendation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I am looking for a book which focuses on constrained optimization, in which topics such as the Lagrange multiplier are discussed in a detailed way. The book should not be "for engineers". It should have a more mathematical insight (proofs, theory; not only examples). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bertsekas book 'Nonlinear Programming' is very nice.

Comment: thanks! will have a look on that

Comment: Also Boyd's Convex Analysis - https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/. It's more analysis than optimization, but very well written and gives a good theoretical background for optimization